# Need help with Reports and Dashboards

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have a custom object "Case Status History" which is a kind of audit log of the Case Status Change. Whenever a Status of a Case is updated , a record is created in this object. Status Values has picklist values as(CSO Working, DA Working, OF Working, New) . When the status changes then the name of the person working on Case is captured as "Record Owner" in the "Case Status History" record. Now I have to create report and Dashboard to display **"Number of Cases being worked by each CSO and DA"**.

For this I have created a new report type "Cases with Case Status History". Now I want to display "User Name" on the X-axis and "Number of Cases Worked" on Y axis. Usernames should be the ones which had worked as CSO or DA only. So in my report i have put a filter for that.

I am getting the record count of "Case Status History" on Y-axis instead of "Record count of Cases" . How can I change that on Y-axis ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, because i can't get all the details of your questions...but if you want to count distinct objects you need to use the [power of one](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields) - check example 3 there. You can then count only distinct objects in a report instead of all objects.

Comment: After creating the new formula field I am unable to see it in my reports.

Comment: Have you added it in the report builder via drag and drop? I've found a very detailed example [here](http://www.ebsta.com/blog/salesforce-hack-power-of-one/) - check it out and if it helps, let us know.